# PowerShell Start-Process -Wait does not wait for VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, wait, powershell-core

In PowerShell Core, spawning VS Code like this, to start a diff/merge:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('LOCALAPPDATA'))\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\code.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList "-n --diff $FullFileNameSrcFrom $FullFileNameSrcTo"
```

works, but it does not wait. I think that's because code.exe starts child processes. If that's the case I could use `-Passthru` and do something like:

```
Get-Process *some criteria here* | ... and check if the children processes are finished
```

But: What could be the *criteria*?

I used `procexp` to try to find it out, but no success.

How can I identify the processes spawned by Code?

Maybe there is an easier way?

I use git with VS Code as my default commit editor and obviously git waits for VS Code to terminate before continuing - so "they" found a way to do this. Does that give me/you a hint?

Comment: These worked for me:  `start -wait code` `start -wait 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe'`

Comment: Open PowerShell (core 7). Type in: `start -wait code`. it starts VSCode, but PowerShell immediately returns to the prompt and is prompting for the next command. It does not wait for VSCode to terminate before. That's on my machine (Win11) anyways. You are positive it's the way you describe on your machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Start-Process -Wait` will also wait for child processes ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3)):

> When using the **Wait** parameter, `Start-Process` waits for the process tree (the process and all its descendants) to exit before returning control. This is different than the behavior of the `Wait-Process` cmdlet, which only waits for the specified processes to exit.

I don't know why, but *waiting* does not work for all processes. It does not even work for `calc.exe`, but it certainly works for some processes.

There is a workaround for your problem with VS Code. It supports a [*wait* option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) itself:

> `-w` or `--wait`  Wait for the files to be closed before returning.

You can do your diff/merge like this, where `Start-Process` *will* actually wait:

```
Start-Process code -ArgumentList "-n -d -w .\test1.txt .\test2.txt" -Wait
```

You do not even need `Start-Process`. This will also wait:

```
code -n -d -w .\test1.txt .\test2.txt
```

Comment: Nicely done. As for why `Start-Process -Wait` isn't effective in this case: Once Visual Studio Code is running, its `code` CLI delegates launching additional instances to the already running instance, and then exits. A running instance is  obviously _not_ a child process of the CLI process at hand. (Behind the scenes, the initial launch spawns 9(!) `Code` processes, and each additional window spawns 3 more.)