# -Wait and -Passthru "gets ignored" if the executed msi installer asks for permission initially

Tags: mysql, powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to make a script for checking in a PC have a certain application with the right version already installed in it (MySQL 8.0.32 in my case), and execute a predownloaded msi file to install it if it doesn't exist. I already have the checking part and now I'm working on the execute an installer part. I'm currently getting an unexpected result because when I invoke the installer with `Start-Process -FilePath <installer path> -Wait`, it seems that the "allow this msi to run" Dialog nullifies the `-Wait` and makes `PowerShell` think the installation process is already over. I then found a code that uses `-PassThru`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here's what my current code looks like:

```
$desiredGoVersion = "go1.20.4"
$desiredMySQLVersion = "8.0.32"

function Install-MySQL{
    $installerFileName = "mysql-installer-community-", $desiredMySQLVersion, ".0.msi" -Join ""
    $desiredMySQLInstallerPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "installers" | Join-Path -ChildPath $installerFileName
    Write-Host $desiredMySQLInstallerPath

    if (Test-Path $desiredMySQLInstallerPath) {
        $proc = Start-Process -FilePath $desiredMySQLInstallerPath -Passthru

        do {start-sleep -Milliseconds 500}
        until ($proc.HasExited)

        Write-Host "MySQL installation process ended."
        Check-MySQL-Install
    } else {
        Write-Host "MySQL installer not found at specified path."
    }
}

function Check-MySQL-Install {
    $registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE"
    $propertyName = "Version"

    $foundVersion = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryPath -Name $propertyName

    if ($foundVersion -eq $desiredMySQLVersion) {
        Write-Host "MySQL version $desiredMySQLVersion is already installed."
    } else {
        Install-MySQL
    }
}
```

I also tried to run the script on a admin mode `PowerShell` but what happened is that the dialog just didn't show up. `-Wait` still didn't wait for anything.

UPDATE:

I tried
`msiexec /a $installerFileName TRANSFORMS=transform.mst TARGETDIR=C:\Program Files\MySQL` and it ends at lightspeed. So fast that I had to force shutdown my PC because the retries are happening in a few ms and I can't kill the script from the terminal. I also found `msiexec.exe /i "yarn-1.10.1.msi" INSTALLDIR="C:\programs" /qb` but it also didn't work. Both of them seems to show that Windows Installer dialog that shows the flag someone can use but I think I'm using the correct tags

UPDATE:

After some realization, I think `PowerShell` isn't the way for installing MySQL. I already found that you can do an unattended install of MySQL and figuring out how to do it

Answer (score 1):

[`Start-Process -Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) will wait for child processes, but it is not aware of new instances that may be spawned by the initial instance of it. In this case, you have to look for wait parameters that are supported by the installer itself, like in this similar question: [PowerShell Start-Process -Wait does not wait for VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75762648/11942268)

As you are using an MSI, you can try to use [`msiexec.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec) explicitly to call your MSI and add parameters for a silent installation, like `/qn`.

[How to install MySQL unattended with custom settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51293749/11942268) covers unattended a. k. a. silent installation of MySQL quite well.

Comment: Should I use something like `msiexec.exe /i "C:\example.msi"`?

Comment: Just tried `msiexec.exe /i` and it still didn't wait for the installer

Comment: I've been seeing `/qn` from other answers, but my concern about it is that how can I setup MySQL if I made the installation hidden?

Comment: So you want to start the installer by PowerShell, but then sit in front of your screen and manually control the installer in the GUI?

Comment: But how can I setup MySQL when the installer is launched through `PowerShell`?